# How to find the number of edges bewteen any two nodes using networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

Exist any form to count the number of edges that separe 2 nodes, for example if we have the nodes "a", "b", "c" and "d" with a form "a"-"b"-"c"-"d" (where "-" is a edge) I need count the edges between "a" and "d".

the real example is as follow. I have a big graph, but in this link you can see a image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7GayK8MGGtCcVhRMncyM0VMc2c/view?usp=sharing

graph have 2806 nodes in this case, and I need to know for example how many edges separe the node 608 of 616. I thought that number_of_edges function can help me, but i think now that only returns if 2 nodes are connected or not (because returns 1 or 0 in a code like this)

```
    for k in id1: #id1 is a list of nodes
        for l in id2: #id2 is a list of nodes
            print graph.number_of_edges(k,l)
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Your question will continue to get down voted unless you provide an example of code that shows your attempted solution.  With your code you should have an example graph where your code fails.

Comment: Look at my answer below.  From your graph image 608 and 616 are connected but not adjacent.  So calling 'graph.number_of_edges(608, 616)' will return 0.

Comment: yes, I saw your answer, for this purpose I change the form of the question and now my question is if exist a function that count the number of edges between nodes (and thanks for your answer, now I know that the function only say the adjacent nodes and not how many edges exist between 2 nodes separated by others nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what you have attempted and without an example graph I will give you a simple example.  It might clear things up for you.

I will make a 4 node, 4 edge graph from an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) using newtworkx and numpy.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

adjacency_matrix = np.array([[0,1,0,1], [1,0,1,0], [0,1,0,1], [1,0,1,0]])
print adjacency_matrix
```

This prints our graph:

```
[[0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]]
```

Now feed this adjacency matrix into networkx as such:

```
rows, cols = np.where(adjacency_matrix == 1)
edges = zip(rows.tolist(), cols.tolist())
gr = nx.Graph()
gr.add_edges_from(edges)
```

Plot it:

```
nx.draw_networkx(gr)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now we can look at which nodes are connected to one another by:

```
print gr.number_of_edges(0, 1) # clearly has an edge
print gr.number_of_edges(2, 0) # no edge between 2 and 0
```

And as expected this prints:

```
1
0
```

So if you are getting `0` from `number_of_edges(a, b)` then a and b are not adjacent (not edge between them).

[**EDIT**: If we want to find all paths between 2 and 0 you can do the following

```
for path in nx.all_simple_paths(gr, source=2, target=0):
    print(path)
# prints
# [2, 1, 0]
# [2, 3, 0]
```

Or to find the shortest path:

```
p = nx.shortest_path(gr,source=2, target=0)
# [2, 1, 0]
```

In which case you could say:

```
num_edges = len(p) - 1 # num_edges = 2
```

]

Comment: ok, but in this page http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.number_of_edges.html say "Return the number of edges between two nodes." I did understand that its count the number of edges that separate 2 nodes

Comment: So number_of_edges(a, b) returns 0 if the edges are not adjacent, meaning they have no explicit edge between them.  To find what I think you are looking for see my edit where you can find the shortest path between you nodes (example: between 608 and 616 in your image, the length of the shortest path -1, will give 2.